# Storing and retrieving a checkbox's value in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension and I want to be able to save and read the status of a checkbox (formatted to look like a switch) to affect how the program runs.

At the moment I can't even access the checkbox in any way, granted I've never used javascript in any capacity before. To test if I can even read the current state I've used
    console.log(document.getElementById("activeSwitch").checked)
or some variant thereof.

This is my popup html I'm using to create the button

```
<head>

    <title>test</title>

    <script src="popup.js"></script>

    <style>
        .switch {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 60px;
            height: 34px;
        }

            .switch input {
                opacity: 0;
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
            }

        .slider {
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color: #ccc;
            -webkit-transition: .4s;
            transition: .4s;
        }

            .slider:before {
                position: absolute;
                content: "";
                height: 26px;
                width: 26px;
                left: 4px;
                bottom: 4px;
                background-color: white;
                -webkit-transition: .4s;
                transition: .4s;
            }

        input:checked + .slider {
            background-color: #2196F3;
        }

        input:focus + .slider {
            box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
        }

        input:checked + .slider:before {
            -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
            -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
            transform: translateX(26px);
        }

        .slider.round {
            border-radius: 34px;
        }

            .slider.round:before {
                border-radius: 50%;
            }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <p><b>test extension</b></p>

        <label id="activeSwitch" class="switch">

            <input type="checkbox" checked/>

            <span class="slider round"></span>

        </label>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: The popup is a separate window with its own devtools: right-click the popup, and click `Inspect`.

Comment: @wOxxOm that makes sense, so if document refers to elements on the page itself, what statement would I use to look for elements on the popup?

Comment: What is "page itself"? Your popup.js runs inside only one page, one document, which is the popup page/document.

Comment: You may want to move `<script src="popup.js"></script>` right before the closing `</body>` tag so it runs when the entire DOM is built.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for your help, it was a combination of things. Moving the script to the end, and a beginner mistake of giving the label the ID rather than the actual input object.